# array value not updating

Tags: c, gdb, printf, strtok

I have a strtok implementation (sort of), but it doesn't print the token!

```
char *tokenizer(char s[], const char *delimiter) {
     char *p;                   //return value of function
     int i = 0;
     while(s[i] != *delimiter)  //to get the size of array just right
         i++;

     char arr[i+1];
     p = arr;                  //can't return an array, so assigned to a
                               //pointer       
     int j = 0;
     i = 0;
     while(s[i]!=*delimiter) {
           arr[j] = s[i];
           i++;
           j++;
     }
     arr[j] = '\0';     
     printf("%s\n",p);         //this statement works, but if excluded
                               //main prints nothing.
     return p;
}
```

This function is being called as following, from the main:

```
char s[] = "tab-tab";
const char del[2] = "-";
char *p;
p = tokenizer(s, del);
printf("%s\n", p);        //prints nothing without the printf in
                          //tokenizer
```

I tried debugging with gdb, and inspected the values of local variable after each line. `p` is updated with `arr[j]` inside `tokenizer` but goes to zero as soon as `tokenizer` finishes and frame shifts back to `main`.

The value of`p` in `main` doesn't become `NULL`, it becomes an empty string, and prints that!

However, `p` in `main` prints the token if `printf` in `tokenizer` is included.

This already includes work-around. I know this can't possibly be the way strtok is implemented. I started with a more sophisticated, "expertish" version which had pointers, but couldn't get it to work, so settled for this "beginner" version.

Comment: the returned variable `p` is pointing to a local variable in the body of the function.  When the function exits, that local variable goes out-of-scope so cannot (shouldn't) be accessed.  This is a major problem.  Suggest allocating `arr[]` from the heap, perhaps via `calloc()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your pointer is pointing to a memory address in the stack, once your function is returned the memory address being pointed to no longer exists, you need to create dynamically allocated memory to access the variable outside of the function. The beauty of `C`

```
char *tokenizer(char s[], const char *delimiter) {
    char *arr;

    int i = 0;
    while(s[i] != *delimiter)
        i++;
    // Initialize variable in the heap
    if (!(arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (i+1))))
        return NULL;
    // Clear the array
    bzero(arr, (i+1));      
    int j = 0;
    i = 0;
    while(s[i]!=*delimiter) {
        arr[j] = s[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    arr[j] = '\0';
    // return pointer
    return arr;
}
```

You should make sure to free the memory in the main to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: That does work! But I wanted to ask that : 1. pointer still pointed to stack on previous version, but both print statements worked, even the one in main. (given that printf in tokenizer is included). 2. What should I free in main? The char * to which stores the result of tokenizer ?

Comment: 1. It didn't work for me, It only printed the one in the function and nothing in the main. 2. Yes, you should free the `pointer` that stores the tokenizer

Comment: Oh Okay! Thanks for help!

Comment: `while(s[i] != *delimiter)` has undefined behavior if `s` does not contain the delimiter.

Comment: @MRR no problem! chqrlie is right about your delimeter, I didn't do any error checking on your code only my addition. Happy coding :)

Comment: @chqrlie I’ll check against ‘\0’ too! Thanks! It’s that when I ask a question I usually strip out all error checking, and the most simple version of program to focus on problem! But I wasn’t checking against ‘\0’ in original version either, so, Thanks again!